# symfony 2, not fully authenticated after login

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

My security.yml is as follows:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Taden\MainBundle\Entity\Employee:   
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 2
            encode_as_base64: true

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: Taden\MainBundle\Entity\Employee, property: code }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            anonymous: ~

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login: ~
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login
            http_basic: ~
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
      - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
      - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

My loginAction() is as follows:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get the login error if there is one
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) 
    {
      $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } 
    else 
    {
      $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
      $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    if ($error != null) 
    {
        $error_message = $this->get('translator')->trans($error->getMessage());
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', $error_message);            
    }

    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'))
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('menu'));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'not logged in'); 
    }

    return $this->render('TadenMainBundle:Default:login.html.twig', array(
        'company_name' => '',
        'department_name' => '',
        'user_name' => '',
        'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
    ));
}
```

On localhost it works without problem. On production server login page is displayed again
after correct credentials. I checked that database connection is working without problem. The problem is isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') returns false. 
It doesn't help if I use

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/menu" />
```

in login.html.twig. Can someone point me to the right direction to solve the problem?

Comment: if dev version is working and prod one not, I would point myself to db issues.

Comment: It works as expected, if I put db access code in loginAction() and set flash messages; so I'm pretty sure it is not db issue.

Comment: synergetic: I mean, is the same db? is this db still populated with your original records? I never heard about issue like this

Answer (score 4):

In Symfony 2, you are fully authenticated when your user has an associated Role to itself (at least one).

Try adding a role to your user, and you should see in the debug bar that you are fully authenticated using the role you gave to your user (and then the "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" should be true).

Answer (score 1):

The class Taden\MainBundle\Entity\Employee must implements EquatableInterface

The method should be something like this

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
{
    return $this->id === $user->getId();
}
```

Comment: `return get_class($this) === get_class($admin) && $this->id === $admin->getId()`